# Why is color not working in the Ncurses library in C++?

Tags: c++, colors, ncurses

I'm trying to write an ncurses program in c++ that uses color, except every time I compile it acts like my terminal does not support colors, rejecting me when I include a color check, and not printing in color when not checking colors. My terminal does support colors (the terminal itself is terminator term emulator w/ zsh, have tried on xterm and tty). Is there some option I need to add to g++ to tell it to compile with color support? I don't get any errors during compilation or runtime.

Here's my code if it helps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    if(!has_colors()) {
        printf("Terminal does not support colors \n");  
        return 0;
    }

    initscr();
    start_color();
    init_pair(1, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_RED);
    /* Get terminal dimensions */
    struct winsize w;
    ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
    /* Make X and Y variables global for later */
    extern int x;
    extern int y;
    
    /* Print test text */
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    printw(" This text should be black on red ");
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    refresh();

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The compiled program just spits out "terminal does not support colors" even though it *does*. Excluding the check still doesn't work, just spits it out in monochrome.

And before you ask, yes I googled it, and no it didn't help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689557/ncurses-has-colors-returns-false-what-is-the-problem `ven though it does.` if so, set TERM environment variable to appropriate setting and notify the programs that your terminal really supports colors.

Comment: @KamilCuk Tried that just moments before I posted the question, didn't work sadly :/

Comment: Please kindly be more specific - what have you tried exactly? `erminator term emulator w/ zsh, have tried on xterm and tty` Which terminal emulator are you using? `even though it does.` How do you know your terminal supports colors? What is the value of TERM variable and what value of it have you tested? What system/environment are you using?

Comment: @KamilCuk Sorry for not being specific: I have tried using the following terminal emulators or regular terminals: Terminator, Xterm and default TTY. None of them have worked. All of which usually support colored output.

Comment: `default TTY.` What is "default TTY" (och, you mean the ctrl+alt+f1 ones?)? What does `echo $TERM` outputs? How do you compile your program? `add to g++ to` Why do you use C++ - seems your program is in C? Why call `has_colors()` before `initscr()`? You have to call it below. Please test only with excluded check, or move the check below `initscr()`. And, you should call `endwin()` to make your terminal nice again.

Comment: @KamilCuk aha, those seem to have fixed it :D Calling has_colors after initscr, compiling with gcc instead of g++, works fine now. Thanks!